# How to add hyperlink to a tkinter output text

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a user input using tkinter console for which the bot gives certain set of instructions as output based on user input, in those set of instructions i need a link of website so that if the users click on it, it should get open in a new browser tab but not sure how can i do it ? can anyone please help ?

```
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import webbrowser
from tkinter import scrolledtext

root = tk.Tk()

now = datetime.now()
current_date_time = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
title_text = "Welcome to my world ! - {}".format(current_date_time)
root.title(title_text)

root.geometry("500x400")  
root.configure(bg="#D22730")

# Function to handle user input and generate bot response
def get_bot_response():
    user_input = input_box.get("1.0", tk.END).strip().lower()
    output_box.configure(state='normal')  # Enable editing the output box
    output_box.insert(tk.END, 'User: {}\n'.format(user_input))

    # Check user queries and provide instructions accordingly

    if 'expense report in fusion tool' in user_input or 'expense report' in user_input:
        instructions = "To create an expense report in Fusion Tool, please follow these 
        steps:\n\n"
        instructions += "1. Log in to Fusion Tool using your credentials **https:\\www.fusiontool.com**\n"
        instructions += "2. Navigate to the 'Expense' section.\n"
        instructions += "3. Click on 'Create New Expense Report' or similar option.\n"
        instructions += "4. Fill in the required details such as expense items, amounts, 
        dates, etc.\n"
        instructions += "5. Attach any relevant receipts or supporting documents.\n"
        instructions += "6. Review the expense report for accuracy.\n"
        instructions += "7. Submit the expense report for approval.\n\n"
      

        response = instructions

    else:
        response = "Sorry, I didn't understand your query. Can you please rephrase it?"

    output_box.insert(tk.END, 'Bot: {}\n'.format(response))
    output_box.see(tk.END)  # Scrolls the output box to show the latest



input_box = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, width=60, height=5, font=("Arial", 12))
input_box.pack()


output_box = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, width=60, height=10, font=("Arial", 12))
output_box.configure(state='disabled')  # Disable editing the output box
output_box.pack()


submit_button = Button(button_frame, text="Submit", command=get_bot_response)
submit_button.pack(side=LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to add hyperlink to a tkinter output text
>
> I need a link of website so that if the users click on it, it should
> get open in a new browser tab but not sure how can I do it.

In main.py.

- I add two modules from `tkHyperlinkManager import HyperlinkManager`
  and from `functools import partial`.
- In line 27, I add parameter for `output_box.insert(...`
- In line 54, I add `callbackcallback(url)` function.
- In line 65, create instance for `hyperlink= HyperlinkManager(output_box)`

Snippet:

```
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import webbrowser
from tkinter import scrolledtext
from tkHyperlinkManager import HyperlinkManager
from functools import partial

root = tk.Tk()

now = datetime.now()
current_date_time = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
title_text = "Welcome to my world ! - {}".format(current_date_time)
root.title(title_text)

root.geometry("500x400")  
root.configure(bg="#D22730")

# Function to handle user input and generate bot response
def get_bot_response():
    user_input = input_box.get("1.0", tk.END).strip().lower()
    print(user_input)
    output_box.configure(state='normal')  # Enable editing the output box
    #output_box.insert(tk.END, 'User: {}\n'.format(user_input))
    output_box.insert(tk.END, user_input,
                      hyperlink.add(partial(webbrowser.open,
                                            input_box.get("1.0", tk.END).strip().lower())))

    # Check user queries and provide instructions accordingly

    if 'expense report in fusion tool' in user_input or 'expense report' in user_input:
        instructions = "To create an expense report in Fusion Tool, please follow these \
        steps:\n\n"
        instructions += "1. Log in to Fusion Tool using your credentials **https:\\www.fusiontool.com**\n"
        instructions += "2. Navigate to the 'Expense' section.\n"
        instructions += "3. Click on 'Create New Expense Report' or similar option.\n"
        instructions += "4. Fill in the required details such as expense items, amounts, \
        dates, etc.\n"
        instructions += "5. Attach any relevant receipts or supporting documents.\n"
        instructions += "6. Review the expense report for accuracy.\n"
        instructions += "7. Submit the expense report for approval.\n\n"
      

        response = instructions

    else:
        response = "Sorry, I didn't understand your query. Can you please rephrase it?"

    output_box.insert(tk.END, '\n Bot: {}'.format(response))
    output_box.see(tk.END)  # Scrolls the output box to show the latest

def callback(url):
   webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)

input_box = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root,  width=60, height=5, font=("Arial", 12))
input_box.pack()


output_box = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, width=60, height=10, font=("Arial", 12))
output_box.configure(state='disabled')  # Disable editing the output box
output_box.pack()

hyperlink= HyperlinkManager(output_box)

submit_button = Button(root, text="Submit", command=get_bot_response)
submit_button.pack(side=LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

In tkHyperlinkManager.py module.

Snippet:

```
from tkinter import *

class HyperlinkManager:

    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
        self.text.tag_config("hyper", foreground="blue", underline=1)
        self.text.tag_bind("hyper", "<Enter>", self._enter)
        self.text.tag_bind("hyper", "<Leave>", self._leave)
        self.text.tag_bind("hyper", "<Button-1>", self._click)

        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.links = {}

    def add(self, action):
        # add an action to the manager.  returns tags to use in
        # associated text widget
        tag = "hyper-%d" % len(self.links)
        self.links[tag] = action
        return "hyper", tag

    def _enter(self, event):
        self.text.config(cursor="hand2")

    def _leave(self, event):
        self.text.config(cursor="")

    def _click(self, event):
        for tag in self.text.tag_names(CURRENT):
            if tag[:6] == "hyper-":
                self.links[tag](event)
                return
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Just click link and will to you to page.

Another screesnhot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the document of [`Text.insert()`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/text.htm#M131):

*pathName **insert** index chars ?tagList chars tagList ...?*

> Inserts all of the chars arguments just before the character at index.
> If index refers to the end of the text (the character after the last
> newline) then the new text is inserted just before the last newline
> instead. If there is a single chars argument and no tagList, then the
> new text will receive any tags that are present on both the character
> before and the character after the insertion point; if a tag is
> present on only one of these characters then it will not be applied to
> the new text. If tagList is specified then it consists of a list of
> tag names; the new characters will receive all of the tags in this
> list and no others, regardless of the tags present around the
> insertion point. If multiple chars-tagList argument pairs are present,
> they produce the same effect as if a separate pathName insert widget
> command had been issued for each pair, in order. The last tagList
> argument may be omitted.

It means that you can specify the *tag* for a string being inserted, like:

```py
output_box.insert(tk.END, "go to ", "", "http://www.google.com", "url", ...)
```

The above example will assign tag "url" to the hyperlink.

Below is the modified `get_bot_response()`:

```py
# Function to handle user input and generate bot response
def get_bot_response():
    user_input = input_box.get("1.0", tk.END).strip().lower()
    output_box.configure(state='normal')  # Enable editing the output box
    output_box.insert(tk.END, 'User: {}\n'.format(user_input))

    # Check user queries and provide instructions accordingly

    if 'expense report in fusion tool' in user_input or 'expense report' in user_input:
        instructions = ["To create an expense report in Fusion Tool, please follow these steps:\n\n"]
        # assign tag "url" to the hyperlink
        instructions += [["1. Log in to Fusion Tool using your credentials ", "", "https://www.python.org", "url", "\n"]]
        instructions += ["2. Navigate to the 'Expense' section.\n"]
        instructions += ["3. Click on 'Create New Expense Report' or similar option.\n"]
        instructions += ["4. Fill in the required details such as expense items, amounts, dates, etc.\n"]
        instructions += ["5. Attach any relevant receipts or supporting documents.\n"]
        instructions += ["6. Review the expense report for accuracy.\n"]
        instructions += ["7. Submit the expense report for approval.\n\n"]

        response = instructions

    else:
        response = ["Sorry, I didn't understand your query. Can you please rephrase it?"]

    output_box.insert(tk.END, 'Bot: ')
    for line in response:
        if type(line) is list:
            output_box.insert(tk.END, *line)
        else:
            output_box.insert(tk.END, line)
    output_box.see(tk.END)  # Scrolls the output box to show the latest
    output_box.configure(state="disabled")
```

Then you need to bind the mouse click event on the *tag* to open the hyperlink using `webbrowser.open()`:

```py
output_box = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, width=80, height=10, font=("Arial", 12))
output_box.configure(state='disabled')  # Disable editing the output box
output_box.pack()

def open_link(event):
    # get the index of mouse click position
    current = output_box.index(f"@{event.x},{event.y}")
    # find the hyperlink under the mouse click
    ranges = list(output_box.tag_ranges("url"))
    for start, end in zip(ranges[::2], ranges[1::2]):
        if output_box.compare(start, "<=", current) and output_box.compare(current, "<", end):
            url = output_box.get(start, end)
            webbrowser.open(url)
            break

output_box.tag_bind("url", "<1>", open_link)
output_box.tag_config("url", foreground="blue", underline=1)
```